# eigenvalue distribution of random projection

Tags: random-matrices

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements and $\Pi$ is a random $k\times n$ matrix that could be 
(a) i.i.d. Gaussian, or
(b) $k$ rows of a random orthogonal matrix

The matrix I am considering is $X = \mathbb{E}\{\Pi^T (\Pi A^{-1}\Pi^T )^{-1} \Pi\}$. I know that $\mathbb{E}\{\Pi A^{-1}\Pi^T\} = \frac{\|A^{-1}\|_1}{n} I$ but $\Pi$ is correlated with what gets multiplied outside the inverse. So I have no good idea how to analyse the eigenvalues of $X$. Numerical experiments suggests that large eigenvalues of $X$ are about the same. Any explanations for this?

Thanks.

Comment: A projection of $\mathbb R^n$ onto a $k$-dimensional subspace is not a $k \times n$ matrix, it's $n \times n$ with $k$-dimensional range.  Perhaps you mean $k$ rows from a random orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, that's exactly what I meant

Comment: youe want to first take the expectation value of the matrix between curly brackets and then study its eigenvalues? the eigenvalues of the matrix _before_ taking the expectation value are much simpler to find....

Comment: @CarloBeenakker So what are the eigenvalues of the matrix inside the curly brackets?

Comment: well, since $\Pi\Pi^T=\mathbb{1}$ (exactly in your case (b) and approximately in case (a) for $k\ll n$), and since the matrix products $AB$ and $BA$ have the same set of nonzero eigenvalues, the nonzero eigenvalues of $M=\Pi^T (\Pi A^{-1}\Pi^T )^{-1}\Pi$ are those of $Y=(\Pi A^{-1}\Pi^T )^{-1}$, which has an inverse Wishart distribution.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker That means $\Pi A^{-1}\Pi^T$ has a Wishart distribution. The definition of Wishart distribution is $X^T X$, where the rows of $X$ are i.i.d. multidimensional Gaussian. So $X = A^{-1/2}\Pi^T$ in my case, but why are the rows i.i.d.? I think the columns of $X$ are i.i.d. in my case.